# Tool for compressing data in JPEG lossless format

Tags: compression, jpeg

I have a file which contains raw pixel data and I want to compress this data using JPEG lossless compression. I tried to search for this tool using google but couldn't fina any. Does anybody know here of any tool which takes raw data as input and compresses it using JPEG lossless format?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: By 'raw pixel data', do you mean a camera RAW format? Also, do you specifically mean JPEG-LS format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) or will lossless JPEG 2000 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) do?

Answer (score 2):

[XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnview.html), view/convert over 400 graphic file formats (incl. various RAW standards)

a [portable version](http://xnview-portable.en.softonic.com/) is also available.

Comment: +1, XnView seems to support JPEG-LS (jls) file export. Should be checked out.

Comment: From the XnView features page: `Export about 50 graphic file formats` which includes `jls` and `JPEG 2000`.

Answer (score 2):

I find irfanview from http://irfanview.net faster than xnview

Answer (score 1):

These are starter pointers for **Lossless JPEG compression**,

- Wikipedia [Lossless JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG)
- [A jpeg-ls page](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~jakulin/jpeg-ls/) (not much updated but refers [a C++ JPEG-LS library CharLS](http://charls.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=JPEG-LS-Performance))
- another [implementation ref](http://itohws03.ee.noda.sut.ac.jp/~matsuda/mrp/)
- There may be some solutions at the [JPEG Solutions page](http://www.jpeg.org/jpegsolutions/search.phtml)

  - May have missed something but I could not find
    **Lossless JPEG writing** capabilities in either **REA** or **Contenta** products,
    right up to the Pro edition.

Is there a specific reason for targetting lossless JPEG?
Would the RAW and other lossless formats not work?

Answer (score 0):

[REA Converter](http://www.reaconverter.com/) can convert RAW images to various formats, and have a lite edition that is free. THere is also the [Contenta RAW Convert](http://www.contenta-rawconverter.com/encyclopedia/raw_files.php?output=JPG&service=convert) however it is not free.